# Animar la información de la hora de un mensaje de un chat

Tags: jquery, aplicación-web, animación, frontend

Estoy trabajando para una página en desarrollo, estoy encargado del *frontend* en el módulo del chat, necesito hacer que cuando el usuario haga click sobre un mensaje enviado se muestre de forma animada la hora en la que se envió el mensaje y, al darle click nuevamente, esa información vuelva a ocultarse.

```
$("#mensaje").click(function(){

   $(this).attr("clickeado","si");

});
```

Lo que se me ocurrió, como podrán ver, fue asignarle como "id" al div html que contiene el mensaje empleando JQuery, un indicador de cuando el contenedor fue clickeado, y en base a eso necesito una condición para que, si "clickeado"es igual a "si", la propiedad *visibility* de la hora sea "visible", y al darle click de nuevo "clickeado" sea igual a "no" y, por el contrario, se oculte la información.

Si alguien por favor pudiera ilustrarme un ejemplo de como hacerlo, lo agradecería muchísimo.

Comment: puees usar el metodo toggle de jquery.. asigna una clase o la elimina... https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! ya lo implementé, sí, funciona bien

Comment: @Edani entonces ponlo como respuesta, y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. No olvides leer además [answer].